# Delete Unused Search Application Databases

Tags: search, central-administration

Can you please let me know if there is any process of deleting the unused search service application databases using Power shell .Even i deleted the search service application the databases are still there and they are showing up in central administration

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the PowerShell Commands [Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608088.aspx) and [Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchPropertyDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607548)